# React-Typescript Hello World

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to Hello World React with Typescript. I wrote the code below. This code works when I use method 1, but throws error on method 2

`Method 1` - `TypeScriptComponent.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'

interface TypeScriptComponentProps {

}

function handleClick() {
  console.log("Hello World")
}

export const TypeScriptComponent = (props: TypeScriptComponentProps) => <Button onclick={handleClick()} bsClass="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></Button>;
```

This code works (with a bit unexpected behaviour with handleClick function, which I can resolve later.)

But this method wont work

`Method 2` - `TypeScriptComponent.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button'

interface TypeScriptComponentProps {

}

function handleClick() {
  console.log("Hello World")
}

export default class TypeScriptComponent extends React.Component<TypeScriptComponentProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return (<Button onclick={handleClick()} bsClass="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></Button>)
    }
}
```

Method 2 throws error

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/TypeScriptComponent.tsx:43:70 
>       TS2339: Property '_ *proto* _' does not exist on type '() => any'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/TypeScriptComponent.tsx:46:5 
>       TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

I am not able to figure out what is the difference between the two methods? Why those errors??

Comment: Can you tell use which lines are `43` and `46` please. This would help to identify your problem.

Comment: Thats an issue as well @SebastianSebald , I'm using Typescript with webpack, so it messes with line numbers.  My file `TypeScriptComponent.tsx` looks exactly same as I posted. There are no 43/46 lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues.

1. Because TypeScript adheres the ESModule specification you have to import React with `* as React from 'react'`. Same for ReactDOM.
2. If I am using your input path for the `Button` TypeScript can not find anything there.
3. If I am using the correct path, TypeScript will tell you that there is no `onclick` prop on `Button`. Only an `onClick`.
4. The way you're passing the click handler to `onClick` doesn't make any sense. You have to pass the function not the return value of the function.

Here is what works for me:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface TypeScriptComponentProps {

}

function handleClick() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}

class App extends React.Component<TypeScriptComponentProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return (<Button onClick={handleClick} bsClass="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window">Click Me!</Button>)
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

My config is using `ts-loader` not `at-loader`. Did you add the `CheckPlugin` to your webpack config?  Otherwhise you will not get any type errors.

If you're new or unfamiliar with Webpack/TypeScript/React-combo, I would suggest checking out this fork of `create-react-app`: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript :)

Comment: Yes, it works now. Maybe I did some extra configuration so it gave some errors. I used minimum config required to make typescript work so now it works. Thanks a lot